# Youtube API: HttpError 403 when requesting URL . Json returned "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota"

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

Enviroment:
　OS: windows 64bit
python version: Python 3.7.4
pyenv version:  Pyenv global 3.7.2

I have already installed API(Youtube Data V3) from GCP and got API key, the module for python(google-api-python-client) as well

I have tried to use Youtube API(youtube Data V3) with python, but Many time I caught the error below

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%B2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0&order=viewCount&type=video&key=AIza*******************&alt=json returned "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota">quota</a>.">
```

this is python code

```
import os
from apiclient.discovery import build
YOUTUBE_API_KEY = os.environ['YOUTUBE_API_KEY']

youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=YOUTUBE_API_KEY)
print(youtube)


search_response = youtube.search().list(
    part='snippet',
    q='RIZEN',
    type='video'

).execute()
```

I have just read the the document(https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors)but I couldn`t understand what is the rootcause of the error because of lack of my experience.

I would be happy if you share your knowledge.

Comment: There is a quota using YouTube API, read the error message correctly: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

I have read the error message again and again but i couldn't understand what i  have to do.

is 'quota' meaning about "part", "video", 'q'?
if so, one of those is used by Youtube API so that the error occured?
Sorry for lack of my knowledge and ability to read English(i am japanese) but I completely don't know what I have to do.

Comment: I wrote the code based on a textbook.